# Is there a way to disable jumping on cell border double click in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm going crazy over the jumping "feature" when double clicking a cell border in Microsoft Excel. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. Please explain what the "jumping feature" is? As it is, this is a very poorly worded question and difficult to understand what you are referring to or trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you referring to **auto-fit** to cell contents?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are talking about the 4-direction arrow icon that appears when you hover over a cell border.  When double-clicking on this, it will perform the equivalent of ctrl-arrow key (moving to last filled cell in that direction).

Yes, you can disable this (which will also disable the fill handle and dragging-dropping of cells):

Choose `File`->`Options`->`Advanced`-> In "`Editing Options`" section, 
uncheck  `"Enable Fill handle and cell drag-and-drop."`

Comment: Your interpretation and decyphering skills are ***incredible***. +1